# Can't open Windows Named Pipe for writing?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, named-pipes

I don't understand why I can't even open a named pipe for writing that I created in another process.

I get the error

> 231 (All pipe instances are busy).

The writer (client):

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hpipe;
    DWORD written;
    char msg[] = "play asdf.wav";

    hpipe = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\pipe\\isp-control",
               GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
               0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (hpipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
      WriteFile(hpipe, msg, strlen(msg) + 1, &written, NULL);
      printf("wrote %d bytes of %d: '%s'\n", written, strlen(msg) + 1, msg);

      CloseHandle(hpipe);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("error %d opening pipe (handle %d)\n", GetLastError(), (int) hpipe);
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reader (server) has before created the pipe like this (note the 4 instances, so one should be free, isn't it?)

```
hpipe_ = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\isp-control",
             PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
             PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
             4, // number of instances
             1024 * 16, // output buffer size
             65535,  // input size
             2000, // default timeout ms 
             NULL);
```

and then uses `PeekNamedPipe` to see if there's data to be read with `ReadFile` or send a timeout.

Comment: but are you call `ConnectNamedPipe` in server ?

Comment: Without an [mcve] of the server code it's hard to diagnose the issue

Comment: *note the 4 instances, so one should be free, isn't it?* - but you anyway need call `CreateNamedPipe` **4 time** for create 4 instances (1 call create only single instance). and after connection is broken - you need call `DisconnectNamedPipe` + `ConnectNamedPipe` for listen again for concrete instance

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications about instances. The ``ConnectNamedPipe`` was missing on the server side. Now I get into other errors, but in order not to completely change the question, I started a new one with complete source code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069904/how-to-read-from-windows-named-pipe-with-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 4-th parameter of [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) - `nMaxInstances` - this is *The maximum number of instances that can be created for this pipe.*

so this is not instance count created in single call, but maximum count which can be created. single call to `CreateNamedPipe` always create one (1) instance of pipe. if you want have 4 instance - you need call `CreateNamedPipe` 4 time. also initially pipe created in listening state, so client can just connect to it by call `CreateFile`. but after connection is broken (because client close self handle) and you want accept new client connections for the same pipe instance - you need call  `DisconnectNamedPipe` and then `ConnectNamedPipe` - only after this new client can again connect to the same pipe instance.

but anyway, even if you create only single pipe instance, by single call `CreateNamedPipeA` - first client can connect to it. error 231 - i guess that real source of error is `STATUS_PIPE_NOT_AVAILABLE`(*An instance of a named pipe cannot be
found in the listening state*) - you can check this by call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` after `CreateFile` fail instead `GetLastError()` say that pipe name is valid, no problems with access, but somebody already connect (may be already disconnect) to pipe - never first call to `CreateFile` return this error

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the API, the connection sequence was not clear to me. You're right, it is 0xC00000AC (STATUS_PIPE_NOT_AVAILABLE). But even if I do ``ConnectNamedPipe`` and then ``DisconnectNamedPipe`` in the read loop, I get the same status "all instances are occupied" most of the time. I'll edit the question to have the complete example to show what I'm doing (wrong).

Comment: I started a new question with the complete source code including above tips: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53069904/5599230